# How to make PdfWriter to write at top of pdf file in java using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am generating charts using jfreechart.Now as per my requirement i need to export that chart into pdf using itext in java.Here i am able to export jfreechart to pdf but it is coming at the bottom of the pdf file whereas i want it to be top.
Here is my code..

```
    PdfWriter writer = null;

    Document document = new Document();

    try {
        writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(
                fileName));

        document.open();
        PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();

        PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(width, height);

        Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(width, height,
                new DefaultFontMapper());

        Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width,
                height);

        chart.draw(graphics2d, rectangle2d);

        graphics2d.dispose();
        contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);
```

How to set PdfWriter  to write at the top of the pdf file.Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the template at the bottom of the page:

```
contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);
```

There are different options you can choose from.

You can add the template at another coordinate:

```
contentByte.addTemplate(template, 36, 400);
```

This will add the document at position x = 36 and y = 400. In this case, you need to do your math: instead of 400, you should take the top coordinate of the page (e.g. y = 842) minus a margin (e.g. 36) minus the height of the image.

If can be easier to choose a different option:

```
Image img = Image.getInstance(template);
document.add(img);
```

Now you're template is added in the flow of the document, just like all other high-level objects (just like `Paragraph`s and `PdfPTable`s).